# Mongodb Client connections with node.js issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run my MongoDB connection with my node.js application which gaming platform here I facing the problem of an increasing number of MongoDB connections [Without using any query but its increasing repeatedly] which reaches to 819 and my MongoDB replication server stop responding and indirectly application stop the work. But I want to maintain a minimum of 20 connections on how to solve these issues please help me.

**

> Mongodb connection: const connectionString =
>   'mongodb://AAAA:PASSWORD@HOST1:27001,HOST2:27002,HOST3:27003/dbName?replicaSet=rep1';
>
> MongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err, database) {
>           if
>   (err) {
>                 console.log(err);
>                 console.log("unable to connect Mongodb database on url: " + connectionString);
>   } else {
>   dbs['dashboardLog'] = database;
>                 console.log("Mongodb database connected to server on url: " + connectionString);            }       });

**

I am using MongoDB client driver version: 3.4.23
Node.js: version 6.11

Fade-up with this issue please helps thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

MongoClient already comes with connection pool support, just set the value you want for `poolSize`, if I remember correctly the default is 5 so set it to 20. You don't have to create a new connection everytime you want to run a new query. Just connect once and then keep that around.

See this article for more information https://blog.mlab.com/2017/05/mongodb-connection-pooling-for-express-applications/